# Unable to access admin URL of Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using powershell and trying to access Azure functions **Administration** using api.
I am trying to get list of all functions created under $appName

Certainly i am changing $appName with actual Azure Function name before call

I also got valid $authToken  before this call.

**Below URL:**

```
$Functions = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = ("Bearer {0}" -f $authToken)} -Uri "https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions"
```

and the error in my powershell execution is :

Invoke-RestMethod :

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At KeyFA.ps1:36 char:18
+ ... Functions = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization =  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I tried make it POST instead of GET but same error.

I tried access this url in broswer and the error in my broswer is :

http 401 means unauthorized.

Then i also tried access this URL from **postman** with Bearer auth correctly set but get below errors:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to 
https://appname_comes_here.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/
```

What am i not doing correctly?

Not able to fix this error. Is the url discontinued by Azure function site now?

Comment: have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctions for List Functions

Comment: @Roman Kiss: same error as before  "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error ......"  as mentioned above also..

Comment: Go to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/get, click on the Try it button and type your resource group name and name of the FunctionApp. You should get the details of your FunctionApp.

Comment: or you can check the List of all FunctionApps, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list, click button Try it and then Run. If you have no problem with a connectivity, than the response is list of all your FucntionApps for a specific subscriptionId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you just post the partial PowerShell code and the error information seems to be a network issue, I don't know what real issue you got is and how to fix it.

So I just post my work PowerShell script at here, you can refer to my code to fix your issue.

```
$appName = "<your app name>"
$userName='<your app credential user name>'
$userPWD='<your app credential user password>'

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($appName).scm.azurewebsites.net/api"
$appBaseUrl = "https://$($appName).azurewebsites.net"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName,$userPWD)))

$jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET

$Functions = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = ("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Uri "$appBaseUrl/admin/functions"
```

Note: you can follow the figures below to get the `$userName` and `$userPWD` values.

Fig 1. On Azure portal, open the `Platform features` tab of your Function App and click the `Deployment Center` link

[image]

Fig 2. Select the `FTP` option in the first step of `SOURCE CONTROL` and click the `Dashboard` button to copy the values of `Username` and `Password`, but just use the part of `Username` with `$` prefix as `$userName` in my script

[image]

Comment: @knowdotnet Any update or concern? If it helps, may you mark it?

Comment: Cross-linking similar issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246239/how-to-create-a-azure-function-function-key-when-your-functions-are-set-to-read