# Other ways to stop all the web jobs in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I wanted to stop web jobs with a certain name that are currently running on all apps in an app plan in Azure. I prefer PowerShell, but Azure PS module is lacking compared to az cli, so I ended up with the following, which feels really clunky:

```bsh
Get-AzWebApp
|
where ServerFarmId -EQ '$appPlanId'
|
select Name, ResourceGroup
|
% {az webapp webjob continuous list --name $_.Name --resource-group $_.ResourceGroup --query '[].{Id:id}' | ConvertFrom-Json}
|
% {az webapp webjob continuous stop --webjob-name $webjobName --ids "$($_.Id)"}
```

I'd appreciate advice on better approaches.

Comment: As far as I know, this is an easy way to do that. Powershell is more complicated for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you can use two APIs below of [`WebJobs API`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) for [`Continuous Jobs`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#continuous-jobs) to realize your needs in PowerShell.

1. [List all continuous jobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#list-all-continuous-jobs)
2. [Stop a continuous job](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job)

For how to call these APIs above, you can refer to the [Sample of using REST API with PowerShell](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell).

Meanwhile, please see the document [Deployment credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) to know how to use the credentials in the REST calling. And you can refer to my answer for a similar SO thread [Unable to access admin URL of Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843059/unable-to-access-admin-url-of-azure-functions/54861921#54861921) to know how to get the credential parameters.

Comment: I've read about doing it via Kudu's API, but calling a REST API directly doesn't sound like a cleaner way to do it - it would involve even more boilerplate code and using PS won't add much value, not to mention additional dealing with authentication.